# How wide were the RAM chips in the PlayStation 1?

Tags: memory, chip, ram, sony-playstation

In earlier years, it was common for DRAM chips to be one bit wide, so that an 8-bit machine would use eight of them to form one memory bank. Occasionally, 4-bit-wide chips would be used, e.g. the later models of the Commodore 64 used a pair of 64kbitx4 chips for 64Kbyte.

Looking at the mainboard of the PlayStation 1, which I believe was a 32-bit machine, it seems to have only something like four RAM chips. Were they 8 bits wide? Or even wider?

Comment: Does your question apply to all revisions ? I only ask as I (cannot check at moment, using mobile) have a -vague- thought the later slimmer smaller ps1 "PS-One" had a slightly updated and revised board layout. Not suggesting this meant differing chips but... The "real" one I mean that is, not that curious newish emulated box-o-tricks.

Comment: @AndyF I was thinking of the original version, but also curious if the answer changes in a later version!

Comment: Fair enough ;) As I say I cannot look at the moment sorry, but genuinely thought the extra "also about" was worth mentioning on a comment. :)

Comment: Completely askew: the Acorn Electron uses _four_ 64x1 DRAMs, mapping each CPU access to two RAM accesses. And that's partly why its RAM access is, at its fastest, half the speed of that of a BBC Micro.

Comment: I can't find a schematic, only a picture, which is https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/PSX-SCPH-5001-Motherboard.jpg . I think those are the four [NEC] RAM chips in the lower left corner. I can't seem to find anything for the part numbers (looks like 424805AL?) but they have 28 pins which would be thoroughly consistent with being 8-bit DRAM. 4164 64x1s have 16 pins, including eight address pins and one data. So 12 more than that is within bounds for seven more data pins plus a few more address pins. Not a full five though — 32 bits of address would be extreme density.

Comment: @Tommy That's a good pic, and probably the right one! I've added it, and some explanation of it, to my answer. According to the service manual, the DRAMs are `KM48V514BJ-6-TEL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the PlayStation 1 CPU had a 32-bit data bus, and RAM was always
32 bits wide, spread over one or more chips.

However, there were at least three major revisions of the Playstation
1 hardware and more than half a dozen different mainboards spread
across [a lot of different models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_models).

Information on the earlier models is hard to find. The GameSX wiki
[schematics:console_related_schematics](https://gamesx.com/wiki/doku.php?id=schematics:console_related_schematics) page has service
manuals for the 5500, 7500, 9000 and 101 (PSOne) series, but nothing
for the earlier 1000 and 3000 series consoles.

The 5500 series uses 4 × 8-bit-wide DRAM chips, IC106 through IC109 in
the [service manual](https://gamesx.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=schematics:sony_playstation_scph-5500-5501-5502-5503.pdf) (PDF), as can be seen on pages 23 and 24 of
the scan (PU-18 board 1/5); the chips are at grid references B2
through I2. (The RAM data pins are labeled `IO0` through `IO7`; these
are connected via bus lines `CPH00`-`CPH31` to the `DD0`-`DD31` pins
of the CPU.)

This appears to be the board for which [Tommy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13533/how-wide-were-the-ram-chips-in-the-playstation-1#comment42893_13533) found [a photo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/PSX-SCPH-5001-Motherboard.jpg);
you can see "PU-18" written large in the centre and the four RAM chips
at the left, with adjacent matching IC numbers.

[image: PU-18 board photo]

The data I/O for the RAM are on pins 2-5 and 24-27 of the 28 pin
package. They're second through fifth pins from the top on either side
of the package in this photo, and you can clearly see traces from pins
24-27 of each chip leading to the data bus pins on the left side of
the CPU, and in between those groups of four, groups of four vias
adjacent to the CPU for pins 2-5, routed on the other side of the
board.

I am guessing that the board of the PlayStation you were examining
looks much like this.

The 7500 series ([service manual](https://gamesx.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=schematics:sony_playstation_scph-7500_service_manual.pdf) PDF) changed to use a single
32-bit wide 16 Mbit DRAM (IC106).